# Quota limit exceeded but no quota used?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Morning, everyone,

I come here today because I have a problem with the youtube API. I upload every day about 50 videos via the API, but I don't understand why since 3 days no more videos can be uploaded, the error I'm given is an overrun of the allowed quotas, which is strange because in the youtube API console, no quota has been used for 3 days (because of this error no video can be uploaded) ... ?

Thank you for you help

Comment: the quota should reset at midnight Westcost usa time.  What is the full error message you are seeing?

Comment: @DaImTo Here is the full error message : "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.",
    "errors": [ { "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.", "domain": "youtube.quota", "reason": "quotaExceeded", "debugInfo": "Code: 8; Description: ?metric=youtube.googleapis.com/default&limit=defaultPerDayPerProject&qs_error_code=INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS"}]}}

Comment: It doesn't seem to get reseted

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have just run into the same exact error and issue. No quota used, and it has been 24 hours. I am seeing the same code 8 error with the INSUFFICIENT_TOKENS flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is youtube changed their API access, now in order to access their API one must apply and get accepted by their API compliance form